# Job should fail in SSIS, if user try to import comma separated file in pipe delimited flat file configuration

Tags: ssis

i have created the SSIS package to load the pipe delimited flat file data into the Sql server destination table.To Achieve this i have used Data flow task, flat file source and ole db destination. I have configured the flat file connection manager with pipe delimiter as  a column delimiter and row delimiter as a "CRLF". in this case, for me package is successfully imported pipe delimited flat file data into the SQL server destination table. Now question is, Do we have any option to fail the Job if user try to import comma separated file?. while i am trying to import comma separated file, job is not getting failed and no records have moved to destination table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can validate the file with a simple script task before running the data flow, suppose you expect 5 pipes on your rows then:

```
    Dim x As New System.IO.StreamReader("your file")
    Dim pipes As String()

    While x.Peek() <> -1
        pipes = x.ReadLine.ToString().Split("|")
        If pipes.Length <> 6 Then
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
            Return
        End If
    End While

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Comment: For example, i have a flat file with 10 rows. among these 10 rows, 5 rows are pipe delimited and remaining 5 rows are comma(",") delimited. in this case we need fail the job and intimate the user like File has invalid formatted records. But while i am trying this type of file, job got successfully load the 5 records which have Pipe delimiter. Remaining 5 records which are having comma delimiter are ignored.

Comment: OK, you need to validate the whole file then. I changed the code to fail the task if at least one row has less or more than 5 pipes.

Comment: yes, this will work. Do we have any other option to validate these type of files apart from this method?. in my case flat file contains more than 5 millions records. if i am going to do the validation in this way, it will take much time. it could be a great, if you share any other options.